# Flutter firebaseFirestore snapshot doesn't work when in release mode IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, ios-background-mode

I want to show notification when something changes in database, it worked fine in debug mode, but when i switch to release mode it works only when the app is active, but in background mode nothing happens.

database listener and notification show

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('companies')
      .doc('VFff15yqjuuM38n9UGMk')
      .snapshots()
      .listen(
    (event) {
      var data = event.data();
      var body = data?["name"] ?? "No name :(";
      createLog(body);
      NotificationUtils.notify(title: 'MyTitle', body: body);
      print("current data: ${event.data}");
    },
    onError: (error) => print("Listen failed: $error"),
  );
```

I believe that event does not fire when in background in release mode
(I tried to make periodic notify every minute and it works)

notify function

```
class NotificationUtils {
  NotificationUtils._();

  static void notify({required String title, String? body}) {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
            channelDescription: 'your channel description',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            ticker: 'ticker');
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    // const IOSNotificationDetails iosPlatformChannelSepcifics =
    //     IOSNotificationDetails();

    globals.flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, title, body ?? '', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
  }
}
```

my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

In xcode I also set capabilities

```
Push Notification
Background fetch
Remote notifications
Background processing
```

Any ideas what could i miss?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Cloud Messages it has a REST api, on any action client can also send messages, it also activates app when its shut down, so probably a much better idea

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging